# Passing Two Values to PHP File Via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

right now I'm successfully passing one value to a Bootstrap modal via AJAX, however when I attempt to pass a second value my code stops working.

**JavaScript**

```
function claimOrder(str, stre){
if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("txtH").innerHTML="Blank Order ID";
return;
}
if (stre=="") {
document.getElementById("txtH").innerHTML="Blank User ID";
return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtH").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}xmlhttp.open('GET','assignuser.php?q='+str'&w='+stre,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Button That Triggers Function**

```
echo '<td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#mModal" onclick="claimOrder('.$order_id.', '.$activeuser.')" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Claim</a></td></tr>';
```

**Modal Called by Button**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div id="txtH"><b>Loading...</b></div>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$w = intval($_GET['w']);
```

etc... No changes were made to the PHP that worked before adding the second variable to the AJAX call except the extra line defining $w. If I remove the extra parameter from the function and function call line assignuser.php runs fine and the modal is populated, so I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `+` in this portion of the code:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','assignuser.php?q='+str'&w='+stre,true);
```

So you will need to adjust it to:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','assignuser.php?q='+str+'&w='+stre,true);
```

Comment: That's all it will take

Comment: Thank you, I've added the + but still no luck

Comment: When you output both values, are you getting any results?

Comment: Nope, if I replace the statement replacing the modal text with the response text with a statement outputting the values I get no results, as if the function wasn't running

Comment: Ahhh I believe the additional issue is that I was trying to pass a string to w, when the php code to handle is: $w = intval($_GET['w']); How should I edit this php to accept a string?

Comment: $w = $_GET['w']; should suffice.

Comment: Odd that this doesn't work... if I change the second variable to an integer and use $w = intval($_GET['w']); it works, when I replace it with a string variable (or predefined string) and $w = $_GET['w']; it doesn't. Is there something in the JS I need to change for it to pass the string along?